# Why Jquery text() method returns error when looping through an array of html tags

Tags: jquery, arrays, text

I have the following jquery code

```
 var arr = $(".input-span").children()
 for (var i =0;i<arr.length;i++){
    console.log(arr[i].text())

 }
```

and the following html code

```
 <div class="input-span">
    input1
</div>
<div class="input-span">
    input2
</div>
```

However when I am executing the previous jquery code, I end up with the following error

**text() is not a function**

Comment: You have HTML elements, not jQuery elements, in your array.  So:  `$(arr[i]).text()`

Comment: thanks both approaches work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you access a jQuery collection using an array index, it returns the DOM element, not a jQuery object. So you can't call jQuery methods on it. You should use a native DOM property like `innerText`, or use `arr.eq(i)` method to get the jQuery object.

Also, your `.input-span` elements don't have any children, so `arr` is empty. I removed the call to `.children()`.

```js
var arr = $(".input-span")
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i].innerText)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-span">
  input1
</div>
<div class="input-span">
  input2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.eq(n)` jQuery method to select the single jQuery object at index `n` and you can use `.text()` and other jQuery method on the resulting object:

```js
var arr = $(".input-span")
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr.eq(i).text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-span">
  input1
</div>
<div class="input-span">
  input2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have HTML elements in your array, not jQuery elements.  So:

```
$(arr[i]).text()
```